# Dynamic Pivot Column by Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-pivot

I have this table:

```
itemid                  attributename   value
6829556334057807840       Part Notes    Drilling Required: No,Install Time: 30 Minutes,Fascia Trimming: Yes (minor),Visibility: Exposed
```

I want to be able to pivot the data in the Value column to a KeyValue pair

```
Example:

    ItemId                  Key                  Value
6829556334057807840       Drilling Required       No
6829556334057807840       Install Time            30
6829556334057807840       Fascia Trimming         Yes (minor)
```

However the pivot must be dynamic because the Value column can have multiple different Key Values depending what is in the column.

Comment: this actually doesn't need to be dynamic pivot.  you simply want to split the delimited strings to rows and then split again to separate columns.

Comment: The *best* solution here is not to store the data like this in the first place. If you can, fix your database rather than trying to get SQL Server to do awkward transformations.

Answer (score 2):

Consider normalization of your database. If you have unknown data, use xml (supported since SQL Server 2005) or JSON (supported since SQL Server 2016). Use this query as a starting point:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        ('6829556334057807840', 'Part Notes', 'Drilling Required: No,Install Time: 30 Minutes,Fascia Trimming: Yes (minor),Visibility: Exposed')
    ) T(itemid, attributename, value)
), Recurse AS
(
    SELECT
        itemid,
        SUBSTRING(value, 1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', value, 1)=0 THEN LEN(value) ELSE CHARINDEX(',', value, 1)-1 END) Item,
        SUBSTRING(value, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', value, 1)=0 THEN LEN(value) ELSE CHARINDEX(',', value, 1)+1 END, LEN(value)) Rest
    FROM Src
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        itemid,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', Rest, 1)=0 THEN Rest ELSE SUBSTRING(Rest, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Rest)-1) END Item,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', Rest, 1)=0 THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTRING(Rest, CHARINDEX(',', Rest)+1, LEN(Rest)) END Rest
    FROM Recurse
    WHERE Rest IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    itemid,
    SUBSTRING(Item, 1, CHARINDEX(':', Item)-1) [Key],
    SUBSTRING(Item, CHARINDEX(':', Item)+1, LEN(Item)) [Value]
FROM Recurse
```

It returns:

```
itemid               Key                   Value
-------------------  --------------------  -------------
6829556334057807840  Drilling Required     No
6829556334057807840  Install Time          30 Minutes
6829556334057807840  Fascia Trimming       Yes (minor)
6829556334057807840  Visibility            Exposed
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with XML:

```
DECLARE @xml xml

SELECT @xml = (
    SELECT CAST('<item id="' + CAST(itemid as nvarchar(100)) +'"><row><key>' +
            REPLACE(REPLACE([value],',','</value></row><row><key>'),': ','</key><value>')+'</value></row></item>' as xml)
    FROM YourTable
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT  t.v.value('../@id','bigint') ItemId,                                    
        t.v.value('key[1]','nvarchar(max)') [Key],
        t.v.value('value[1]','nvarchar(max)') [Value]
FROM @xml.nodes('/item/row') as t(v)
```

For sample of table you provide, output will be:

```
ItemId              Key                 Value
6829556334057807840 Drilling Required   No
6829556334057807840 Install Time        30 Minutes
6829556334057807840 Fascia Trimming     Yes (minor)
6829556334057807840 Visibility          Exposed
```

This is XML data that you get after converting table with `XML PATH` and replacements:

```
<item id="6829556334057807840">
  <row>
    <key>Drilling Required</key>
    <value>No</value>
  </row>
  <row>
    <key>Install Time</key>
    <value>30 Minutes</value>
  </row>
  <row>
    <key>Fascia Trimming</key>
    <value>Yes (minor)</value>
  </row>
  <row>
    <key>Visibility</key>
    <value>Exposed</value>
  </row>
</item>
```